# R coding: bootstrap a dataset with repeated measures

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

My dataset looks like (call it `data_xy`)

```
id X Y
1  5 10
1  6 11
1  4 8
2  3 9
2  3 12
3  4 10
...
```

observations from a total of N ids. Each id has several rows of measurements.

I want to bootstrap the id with replacement. It is very likely that the bootstrap id contains duplicates.

```
b_idx <- sample.int(N,N,T)
```

it's likely that

```
b_idx=c(1,1,3,4,4,4....)
```

Then how to create the bootstrap sample with `b_idx`? If I do

```
data_xy[data_xy$id==b_idx,]
```

each `id` (with its repeated measures) will occur only ones in my bootstrap dataset. What I really want is to replicate the observations for `id=k` the number of times this id occurs in `b_idx`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use the ID directly; you can just sample row numbers, and then directly index the data.frame with those:

```
# How many rows in the data.frame?
n <- nrow(mtcars)

# Sample them
mtcars[sample(x = n, size =  n, replace = TRUE), ]
```

If you pass in the same integer twice, you get that row twice. Here's an example of that principle in action:

```
mtcars[c(1, 1), ]
```

If you don't know it already, be sure to check out [the boot package](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html), which automates a lot of bootstrapping scenarios for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'matches' function from the grr package for this.

```
Indices <- unlist(matches(b.idx, data_xy$ID, list=TRUE))

b.data <- data_xy[Indices, ]
```